# lessc seems to do nothing

Tags: linux, node.js, less

I'm trying to set up `lessc` (from node) in order to use [this eclipse plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-plugin-less/metrics).

Since I'm behind a company proxy and/or firewall (don't know the exact setup), I was unable to directly install less by `npm install -g less`, so I manually downloaded the latest release from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/less), extracted the zip and did `npm install -g <extracted-folder>`, which seemed to work.

However, when navigating to a directory with a .less file and execute `lessc myfile.less`, the command silently finishes and no output file is generated. I've tried manually specifying the output file and setting the `--verbose` flag, but still no output on the command line nor any file.

What is going on here, and how should I continue debugging the issue?

**Workaround**

In case anyone is facing the same problem, here's what I'm currently using as alternative: [Koala](http://koala-app.com/) is a self-contained application to compile LESS (among other things) and is capable doing so immediately after a change, so I keep it running in the background and edit my less file in Eclipse, which gets automatically re-compiled on each save operation.